# How to add List of Abbreviations to Table of contents with a specific group outline

Tags: table-of-contents, nomenclature, nomencl

How can I add my List of Abbreviations and nomenclature to the table of contents with the following code? I tried `\addcontentsline{toc}{?}{?}` but do not know what I should write in last two brackets. Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\renewcommand{\nomname}{}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{8pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\Large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Nomenclature}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{List of Abbreviations}{}}%
]\vspace{10pt}}

\begin{document}

\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{IMO}}{in my opinion}
\nomenclature[N]{$c$}{speed of light in vacuum}

\printnomenclature[2cm]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}`?

Comment: @DavidPurton It doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, adding the option `intoc` at loading time doesn't work, because you don't want to print the `\nomname`.

Instead, you need something like

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
```

Complete example (needs several compilations to get the references right)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\renewcommand{\nomname}{}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{8pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\Large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Nomenclature}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{List of Abbreviations}{}}%
]\vspace{10pt}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{IMO}}{in my opinion}
\nomenclature[N]{$c$}{speed of light in vacuum}


\clearpage
\printnomenclature[2cm]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}

\end{document}
```

And this is what you'll get

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I had tried with {section} but obviously not as it works fine now.